# sheet.copyTo always returns "A server error has occurred" in new Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

No matter what I do I cannot get the sheet.copyTo() function to work in the new Google sheets. Always returns "A server error has occurred".  I've tried converting the source to the new format. Doesn't work with csv files either. Exact same code with exact same sources works flawlessly from the old Google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
           function ctest() {
        var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         var sheet = source.getSheets()[1];
         Logger.log(sheet.getName())

         var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create("testcopy");
        sheet.copyTo(destination);

        }
```